# Speed of python scripts

Tags: python

I have a test python script. On my notebook Asus K73E CPU intel i5-2340M (2 kernels 2,40 GHz) 8MB RAM this script executes for 9.8 seconds. I thought it is too much and buy desctop PC with much performance: AMD Ryzen 5 2600 (6 kernels 3.4GHz) and 18MB RAM PC-24300.
Run on it same script and was shocked: script executes for 8.6 seconds.

New hardware is much higher performance. Why this scrip execution time decreased so a little?

I know how to optimize a script to values less than a second - it is possible to add a line through the list, in this case operating time of a script was 0.186, became 0.126 - that too is not significant gain of productivity.

I in confusion. What are ideas?

```
import time

class Profiler(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._startTime = time.time()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print("Elapsed time: {:.3f} sec".format(time.time() - self._startTime))

def cycle():
    query = ''
    elem = {'sec_code' : "test", 'face_unit' : "test", 'class_code' : "test", 'code' : "test", 'scale' : 'test', 'face_value':'test',
            'lot_size': "test", 'short_name' : 'test', 'name': "test", 'min_price_step' : 'test', 'isin_code': 'test', 'class_name' : 'test', 'mat_date': 'test'}
    for i  in range(45000):

        query = query+ "insert into securyties(sec_code, face_unit, class_code,code, scale, face_value, lot_size,short_name," \
                        "name,min_price_step,isin_code,class_name,mat_date)" \
                        "values ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', {}, {}, {}, '{}', '{}', {}, '{}', '{}', '{}')  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;".format(
            elem['sec_code'],
            elem['face_unit'],
            elem['class_code'],
            elem['code'],
            elem['scale'],
            elem['face_value'],
            elem['lot_size'],
            elem['short_name'].replace("'", ""),
            elem['name'].replace("'", ""),
            elem['min_price_step'],
            elem['isin_code'],
            elem['class_name'], elem['mat_date'])

    #print (''.join(query))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Profiler() as p:
        cycle()
```

Comment: Does your intel have Turbo Boost?

Comment: well, `time.time` is not a great way to measure performance in the first place

Comment: 8MB RAM? Have you checked profiling it?

Comment: I don't believe this code will take advantage of multiple CPU cores (I assume that's what you meant by "kernels".)

Comment: Why would you insert 45000 * 1 value instead of 1 * 45000 values?

Comment: There must be a very big problem with your computer, because it runs in `50ms` on my computer. Well, I do have a memory peak at ~40MB, but I suppose you have 18GB and not 18MB, right?

Comment: I thought its better way to save time on connections to the database (insert 45000 * 1 value instead of 1 * 45000 values). Of course i ment cores (sorry for my english)

Comment: @RomanKozlov But performing one query has a cost, and you multiply that cost by 45000. You probably should group these into 1.

Comment: 16 GB RAM i have.

Comment: @skoeb I am not sure you can do concurrent access to the DB, implementing multithreading instead of profiling is rarely a good idea

Comment: There must be a very big problem with your computer, because it runs in 50ms on my computer. It is the new computer which I just bought. I understand that for performance of such task time is very big (in my opinion). In what place at least to look for a problem?

Comment: implementing multithreading - good idea, i know, but i think something wrong else  Right leg wrote about 50 ms...Why 9 SEC on me?

Comment: My five-year-old laptop says 60ms, so I do not think the issue here is one with the code.

Comment: i try different versions iof python interpretator - results are same +/- 1 second. PyPy interpreter execute script for 148 seconds ))) There are ideas where to look for a problem?

Comment: In profiling info:  1    6.559    6.559    6.618    6.618 learn.py:2(cycle)  1    0.000    0.000    6.618    6.618 {built-in method builtins.exec}

Comment: Same code on Linux machine Python 2.6 executes for few milliseconds (hardware much lower). On Windows7 machine same code runs for 43 seconds. Where look for problem????